# Compare single dimensional array against multidimensional array php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a problem comparing one array with another multidimensional array.

I want to compare array `A` against `B` and check which dates(values) in array A are missing in array B.

In places where there are missing dates, I want to insert a "date" key with "date-value" from array A, along with key "counter" => 0.

```
$A = [
    0 => "2018-03",
    1 => "2018-02",
    2 => "2018-01",
    3 => "2017-12",
    4 => "2017-11",
    5 => "2017-10"
];

$B = [
    0 => [
        'logins' => [
            0 => [
                "date" => "2018-03",
                "counter" => "65"
            ],
            1 => [
                "date" => "2018-02",
                "counter" => "40"
            ],
            2 => [
                "date" => "2017-12",
                "counter" => "77"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    1 => [
        'logins' => [
            0 => [
                "date" => "2018-02",
                "counter" => "44"
            ],
            1 => [
                "date" => "2018-01",
                "counter" => "24"
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

Result array `C` should look like this:

```
$C = [
    [
        'logins' => [
            ['date' => '2018-03', 'counter' => 65],
            ['date' => '2018-02', 'counter' => 40],
            ['date' => '2018-01', 'counter' => 0],
            ['date' => '2017-12', 'counter' => 77],
            ['date' => '2017-11', 'counter' => 0],
            ['date' => '2017-10', 'counter' => 0],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'logins' => [
            ['date' => '2018-03', 'counter' => 0],
            ['date' => '2018-02', 'counter' => 44],
            ['date' => '2018-01', 'counter' => 24],
            ['date' => '2017-12', 'counter' => 0],
            ['date' => '2017-11', 'counter' => 0],
            ['date' => '2017-10', 'counter' => 0],
        ],
    ]
];
```

Comment: Your question is hard to understand, please make a **small sample** data and a **small expected output**, also post what have you tried so far... and yeah, also, Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop over `$B` then on each item loop over `$A`, check if date is found, if not then add it, then sort the array by `$A`.

```
<?php
foreach ($B as &$row) {
    foreach ($A as $date) {
        if (!in_array($date, array_column($row['logins'], 'date'))) {
            $row['logins'][] = [
                "date" => $date,
                "counter" => 0
            ];
        }

    }
    array_multisort($row['logins'], SORT_DESC, $A);
}

print_r($B);
```

https://3v4l.org/6Ri6I

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [logins] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-03
                            [counter] => 65
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-02
                            [counter] => 40
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-01
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-12
                            [counter] => 77
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-11
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-10
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [logins] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-03
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-02
                            [counter] => 44
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-01
                            [counter] => 24
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-12
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-11
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2017-10
                            [counter] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly the solution to my problem.
Thanks!